# strange angularJs variable behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Kindly explain me this behavior. I have decalred 2 variables.

```
$scope.data = {'value' : 123};
    $scope.v1 = $scope.data;
```

Now if i change the value

```
$scope.data.value = 2;
```

and try to print

```
alert('old value is '+$scope.v1.value);
```

It gives me output as 2 whereas I think it should give me value as 123. 
Kindly tell me that is it the same behavior like **Java** where one variable has different instances and change in one reflects in another ?

Comment: It's a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're guessing you are not creating a new object when you assign $scope.data to $scope.v1. You're just "pointing" $scope.v1 to $scope.data which implies that any change that you do to $scope.data will be reflected also in $scope.v1.

If you want to have different elements you should make a copy of the object. Look at [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You want to use angular.copy() to solve your current issue.

Anyways this all happens because of making one Object equal to another is assigning a reference; not creating a copy.